# Help Evaluating Legendre Integral times Polynomial

Tags: definite-integrals

In calculating the multipole moments on the [Maclaurin spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin_spheroid), I've encountered the following integral. The text I'm reading ([Poisson and Will](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/gravity/1F0CF38A59B1E51A63C7C3138268BE5D)) says that the integral is doable.

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \left(1+a x^2\right)^{-\frac{l+3}{2}} P_l(x) d x$$

The constant $a = e^2/\left(1-e^2\right)$ is a function of the spheroid's eccentricity. I'm trying to evaluate it for general $l\in\mathbb{Z}$, but for specific values of $l$ it gives me the correct result (so I'm certain this is the correct integral to evaluate).

I've tried integrating by parts with $P_l(x)\propto \frac{d^l}{dx^l}\left(x^2-1\right)^l$, but the result is just as difficult to crack because then I have $l$ derivatives of the first term in the integrand and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=nth%20derivative%20of%20%281%2Ba%20x%5E2%29%5E%28-%28n%2B3%29%2F2%29) tells me this is a hypergeometric function.

Comment: Have you verified the convergence of the integral? Since $a =\mathrm{e}^2/(1-\mathrm{e}^2)$, this integral does not seem to converge.